# WCF deny unauthenticated users on certain endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service project where I've implemented custom basic authentication by following the [guidelines here](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/), and all is working great! However, I can't find if there is a way to deny unauthenticated users access to only specific endpoints.

In my project, I have about 5 endpoints and only want users to be authenticated against a couple of them. The others, I want to allow anonymous access to.

My web.config (snippet) is as such:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="CustomBasicAuthentication" type="WebServices.Auth.CustomBasicAuthenticationModule, WebServices"/>
    </httpModules>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

    <membership defaultProvider="defaultProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="defaultProvider" type="WebServices.Auth.WSMembershipProvider, WebServices"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

The endpoints are fairly plain as such:

```
<service name="WebServices.Distance" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBinding" contract="WebServices.IDistance" behaviorConfiguration="rest" />
</service>
.... more endpoints below here ....
```

So instead of  hitting all endpoints, can I say to deny unauthenticated users for endpoint #1 (or by name, or whatever).

I hope this makes some sense. If not, feel free to snark. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, easy solution.

Remove the  section and put the following immediately below the  section.

```
  <location path="Secure">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Then just create a folder called "Secure" and put the desired services, along with their interfaces, into that folder.

Perhaps I should have done a little more investigating before posting my question here.